# knockout mapping - multiple data sources into one view model

Tags: javascript, .net, json, knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

I'm currently trying to break down a large section of data, which is provided by a $ajax call to a .NET webservice, that is causing a script timeout on the page when the data is being mapped to a Knockout view model. I noticed in the documentation that you **should** be able to bind multiple data sources to one viewmodel, like so:

```
var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(alice, aliceMappingOptions);
ko.mapping.fromJS(bob, bobMappingOptions, viewModel);
```

I've tried this in my own code, as shown below, and on the first pass I bind to a new view model and then on subsequent passes I attempt to rebind to the same view model:

```
if(currLoadIndex == 0)
{
    currViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
}
else{
    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions, currViewModel);
}
```

However, this just leaves me with the last section of data I've loaded when I bind it to my template. I've tried setting a key in my 'mappingOptions' but that hasn't helped. Can anybody see anything obvious which I'm doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of a more complete view model and perhaps include a sample of the JSON data returned by your webservice?
Typically each set of data would be represented either by an observableArray or a completely separate viewmodel depending on how you want to use the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the best solution out there but this fixed my problem:

```
if(currLoadIndex == 0)
{
     currViewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
}
else{
     var tmpModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mappingOptions);
     for(i = 0; i < tmpModel.GetProductListResult().length; i++)
     {
         currViewModel.GetProductListResult().push(tmpModel.GetProductListResult()[i]);
     }
}
```